# INSERT INTO sql code connection issues

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have successfully managed to use `SELECT` and `DELETE` SQL statements and now I am trying to use `INSERT INTO`. However I keep getting this error:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The
>   connection's current state is closed.

So I tried putting `con.Open()` to see if that would help and I got this error:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

I was wondering if anyone knows what I have done wrong. Or just if anyone has any working code. Preferably I would like to not use parameters if that is possible because I don't understand them at all. Here is my SQL code:

```vb
Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim comm As OleDb.OleDbCommand
con = SQLConnect()
comm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " & TableName & " (" & Column & ") VALUES (" & Value & ")"
comm.Connection = con
comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

**Here is the connection code:**

```vb
Public Function SQLConnect() As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    If Connector.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        dbprovider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbsource = "Data Source = NEA.accdb"
        Connector.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource

        Connector.Open()
    End If
    Return Connector

End Function
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. Why do you need us to repeat what you already know?

Comment: So how do i open an available connection?

Comment: Yes, as @jmcilhinney says, and what is the code of SQLConnect? The first (of many) problem is there.

Comment: You've already opened the connection.  That's why you're not getting that error message any more. Did you even read the second error message?

Comment: If you managed to execute a DELETE operation then you should look at how you have setup the connection there.

Comment: Public Function SQLConnect() As OleDb.OleDbConnection
        If Connector.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            dbprovider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
            dbsource = "Data Source = NEA.accdb"
            Connector.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource

            Connector.Open()
        End If
        Return Connector

    End Function

Comment: I literally copied the delete code and it didnt work

Comment: So if the connection is open you open it again, but if it is close you don't open it? Please [edit] your question to add the code. In comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one open connection and one close connection like this:

1. Open the connection
2. Execute all your DELETE and INSERT queries.
3. Close the connection.

Try this:

```vb
con.Open()
comm.Connection = con

comm.CommandText = "DELETE ..."
comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " & TableName & " (" & Column & ") VALUES (" & Value & ")"
comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

BTW, I recommend that you use parameters instead of string concatenation on your sql query. To avoid sql injection.

Comment: What are the values of con and comm?

Comment: @Owen Declare them like in your code `Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim comm As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    con = SQLConnect()`

Comment: Dont worry i have done it now. Thank you for your help though

Comment: @Owen - You're welcome, if you found my answer helpful, please accept it. thanks.